# converting tsql insert to update correct?

Tags: t-sql

so i'm converting an insert statement into an update statement.

here is the insert

```
    insert into Matches(
     SourceID,
     SourceUniqueID,
     ExtractionNumber,
     ItemID,
     MatchDate,
     MatchBy,
     MatchMethod) 
    select 
      m.SourceID 
     ,m.SourceUniqueID 
     ,m.ExtractionNumber 
     ,m.ExtractionNumber 
     ,getdate() 
     ,replace( suser_sname(),'Bob\','') 
     ,'EMTransmittalnumber' 
    from MatchData as m 
    where m.SourceID = 19
```

Here is the update statement i have so far but it is generating an error

```
update m2 set 
   m2.SourceID = m.SourceID
 , m2.SourceUniqueID = m.SourceUniqueID
 , m2.ExtractionNumber = m.ExtractionNumber
 , m2.ItemID = m.ExtractionNumber
 , m2.MatchDate = getdate()
 , m2.MatchBy = replace( suser_sname(),'Bob\','')
 , m2.MatchMethod = 'EMTransmittalnumber'
 from MatchData as m
    inner join Matches as m2
    m2.itemid = m.extractionnumber 
    where m.sourceid = 19
```

error says incorrect syntax near 'm2'

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you forgot the "on" for inner join:

```
update m2 set  
   m2.SourceID = m.SourceID 
 , m2.SourceUniqueID = m.SourceUniqueID 
 , m2.ExtractionNumber = m.ExtractionNumber 
 , m2.ItemID = m.ExtractionNumber 
 , m2.MatchDate = getdate() 
 , m2.MatchBy = replace( suser_sname(),'Bob\','') 
 , m2.MatchMethod = 'EMTransmittalnumber' 
 from MatchData as m
    inner join Matches as m2 on
    m2.itemid = m.extractionnumber  
    where m.sourceid = 19
```